# Syntax for Select in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE games (name text, date text, winloss int, gameid int, pointsfor int, pointsagainst int);
```

Two sample records would look like:

```
Anna A, 7/12/13, 0, 345, 56, 28
Barley B, 7/12/13, 1, 345, 28, 56
```

(Barley's team lost, and Anna's won. Each game has several players on each team.) I want to create a query that will return all the games that had x players on one team and y players on another, plus the cumulative result of those games.

I know how to do this using perl and a csv file, and I believe that I could use the same method with the dbi interface. I want to learn how to create this report using only SQL queries, however. I am a newcomer to SQL, and I suspect the solution may involve pivoting the table using CASE WHEN or JOIN to create a new table; but I can't see how to do it.

This query will return all the games where the players were on the same team and won (or lost, depending on the value of winloss):

```
select gameid,date from games
where name in ('Anna A', 'Barley B') and winloss=1 
group by gameid 
having count(*)>1;
```

But I don't know how to generalize that query to return games with players on the other team.

Comment: *all the games that had x players on one team and y players on another*  how do you plan on defining `x` and `y`

Comment: By user query. I want to know how many games where player(s) x won against player(s) y. So, all 'Anna A' and 'Barley B' against 'Charley C' and 'Danielle D' for example.

Comment: Something missing, where does number of players come from?

Comment: Do you mean in the query or the table? Each record in the table is as you see above. The games could have ten players on each side or only five. It's variable. For the query, I want it to be user-defined. It could be all 'Anna A.' versus 'Barley B.' or 'Anna A.' and 'Charley C' against 'Danielle D.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the lines for the game or games where A and B won versus C, D and E.

```
select * 
from games 
where gameid in    
    (select gameid from games
        where name in ('Anna A', 'Barley B') and winloss=1 
        group by gameid 
        having count(*) = 2
    intersect
     select gameid from games
        where name in ('Charly C', 'Dave D', 'Ed E') and winloss = 0 
        group by gameid 
        having count(*) = 3) ;
```

Alternatively, you could use :

```
select *
from games where gameid in (
    select gameid from games where name = 'Anna A'   and winloss = 1   intersect
    select gameid from games where name = 'Barley B' and winloss = 1   intersect 
    select gameid from games where name = 'Charly C'   and winloss = 0 intersect
    select gameid from games where name = 'Dave D' and winloss = 0     intersect
    select gameid from games where name = 'Ed E' and winloss = 0
    ) ;
```

whichever suits you best.

You can then add `sum` and `group by` to get cumulative results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
where name in ('Anna A', 'Barley B')
```

change to

```
where name in (SELECT DISTINCT Player FROM games)
```

Comment: Can you have two wheres in the same query? Or do you mean replace the first with the second? That just returns a list of all the games, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, my post wasn't artfully composed. The SELECT I added is referred to as a nested query. I replaces your two hardcoded players with a unique list of players in the table game. I doubt this is the final solution for your overall problem.

Comment: Ok. What I have in mind is all "Anna A" and "Barley B" versus "Charlie C" and "Danielle D." Not to generate a report on all the (vast number of) combinations, but just on user-selected ones.