# Select Query for Repeated Records in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

This problem is a generalization of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861822/syntax-for-select-in-sql-query). Rather than finding all the games with specific players playing against others, I want to be able to find all the games where the same players played against each other.

Here is sample data:

```
1,ChrisEveret,1
1,BillieJeanKing,1
1,RogerFederer,0
1,TomasMuster,0
2,RogerFederer,1
2,SallieMae,1
2,NovakDjokovic,0
2,JimCourier,0
3,ChrisEveret,0
3,BillieJeanKing,0
3,RogerFederer,1
3,TomasMuster,1
```

The desired output is

```
1,ChrisEveret,1
1,BillieJeanKing,1
1,RogerFederer,0
1,TomasMuster,0
3,ChrisEveret,0
3,BillieJeanKing,0
3,RogerFederer,1
3,TomasMuster,1
```

The actual data has only about two thousand rows, so performance is not a concern. I have come up with the following remarkably convoluted and inexact partial solution:

```
CREATE TABLE sets (gameid int, player text ,winloss int);
  .import data.csv sets
  select *  from sets where gameid in
   (select gameid from (select gameid,mo from
    (select gameid,mo,count(*) from
     (select gameid,group_concat(player) as mo from
      (select gameid,player from sets order by gameid,player)
     group by gameid)
   group by gameid)
  where mo in 
   (select mo from (select gameid,mo,count(*) from
    (select gameid,group_concat(player) as mo from
     (select gameid,player from sets order by gameid,player)
     group by gameid)
     group by mo
     having count(*)>1))));
```

This returns all matches where the same four people played together, but not necessarily those in which the teams were the same. I do not know if there is a solution to this problem that does not involve using group_concat(). That is the only way I was able to make even this limited progress on it, however. I also am not sure that the method used to order the group_concat results for aggregation will always work.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not guarantee the ordering using `group_concat()` -- and there is no way to control it.  So you have to use more cumbersome methods.

You can get the pairs of games with the same player using:

```
with s as (
       select s.*, count(*) over (partition by gameid) as num_players
       from sets s
      )
select s1.gameid, s2.gameid
from s s1 join
     s s2
     on s1.player = s2.player and s1.num_players = s2.num_players
group by s1.gameid = s2.gameid
having count(*) = max(s1.num_players);
```

You can then use this logic if you want to get the players in each game (or just use `group_concat()` for that).

EDIT:

Window functions were introduced in SQLite version 3.28.  In earlier versions, try this:

```
with s as (
       select s.*, ss.num_players
       from sets s join
            (select gameid, count(*) as num_players
             from sets s
             group by gameid
            ) ss
            on ss.gameid = s.gameid
      )
select s1.gameid, s2.gameid
from s s1 join
     s s2
     on s1.player = s2.player and s1.num_players = s2.num_players
group by s1.gameid = s2.gameid
having count(*) = max(s1.num_players);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ae3aeb42f6901658d869106b14825b10) is a db<>fiddle that shows all pairs of games that have the same players (note that this includes each team to itself).

Comment: @user2619203 . . . Are you using an older version of SQLite that doesn't support window functions?

Comment: With 3.30.1, the syntax error is near "s." I've tried it several times.

Comment: @user2619203 . . . There was a typo, with the table alias `s` being next to the wrong parenthesis.

Comment: I now get "no such column as s.num_players".

Comment: I changed the line that ends "s1.num_players = s.num_players" to "s1.num_players = s2.num_players" and it ran but returned no results. I don't follow the logic of this at all, so I have no idea if that was what was intended.

Comment: The code now runs and it returns results from my data consistent with the fiddle. It's quick too. But the results show games with all four players, not those with the same two players against the same two players (which winloss column identifies).

Comment: Also the code in the fiddle works, which I think is the same as the second code block, but the code in the first block does not return any results on sqlite version 3.30.1.

Comment: In the fiddle, if I add "s1.winloss = s2.winloss" to join on line, I get the result I want, though I would like to be able to filter out the non-repeats. I'm sure I can figure out the logic for that, though. If you replace the code blocks above with the code from the fiddle, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, adding "s1.winloss = s2.winloss" only returns results where the outcome was the same. I need those where the outcome was different too.

Comment: I could get the desired result by adding a union between a copy of the queries, with one having s1.winloss = s2.winloss and the other having s1.winloss != s2.winloss. That feels like an inefficient solution, however.

Comment: I just wanted to check to see if you were willing to change the code per the comments above.